# Stream screen with objective-c react-native

Tags: objective-c, react-native

I am building a module into my react native app to stream my screen and then send it to a server via a socket connection.
The java par works fine, I am using a method to get a capture of the screen and then send the base64 image to the server.

I do not really know about objective-c, I get a code to take screenshot but it seems some identifiers are not declared, reading the doc about objective-c and react-native I do not know what to import, seems to be automatic.

This is my actual code

```
#import "ScreenShare.h"

@implementation ScreenShare

// To export a module named ScreenShare
RCT_EXPORT_MODULE();

RCT_REMAP_METHOD(start,
                 startWithResolver:(RCTPromiseResolveBlock)resolve
                 rejecter:(RCTPromiseRejectBlock)reject)
{
  NSDictionary *result = @{@"success": @true};

  UIWindow *keyWindow = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow];
  CGRect rect = [keyWindow bounds];
  UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rect.size);
  CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
  [keyWindow.layer renderInContext:context];
  UIImage *img = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
  UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

  resolve(result);
}

RCT_REMAP_METHOD(stop,
                 stopWithResolver:(RCTPromiseResolveBlock)resolve
                 rejecter:(RCTPromiseRejectBlock)reject)
{
  NSDictionary *result = @{@"success": @true};
  resolve(result);
}

@end
```

My h file

```
#import <React/RCTBridgeModule.h>

@interface ScreenShare : NSObject <RCTBridgeModule>
@end
```

and for example, only on this line `UIWindow *keyWindow = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow];` I have:

```
Use of undeclared identifier 'keyWindow'
Use of undeclared identifier 'UIApplication'
Use of undeclared identifier 'UIWindow'
```

Comment: can you show your .h file too?

Answer (score 1):

You should probably include at least

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
```

in either the .h or .m

If you're still having problems, I'd recommend you look at the structure of some other modules (e.g. RNFetchBlob) to get an idea of what's needed.